# If $\{f_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ converges to $f$ in $L^{p}(X,\mu)$, then $\{f_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ converges to $f$ in measure.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let, $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be our measure space. Suppose $\{f_n\}_{n \ge 1} \subset L^{p}(X,\mu ) $ converges to $f$ in $L^{p}(X,\mu)$. We wish to show that $\{f_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ converges to $f$ in measure.  For $z > 0$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we define:
$$E_{k,z}= \{x \in X: |f_k(x) - f(x) | \ge z  \}. $$

We have that,

$$ \forall \lambda > 0, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}: ~ ~ \mu(\{x \in X: |f_k(x) - f(x)|^{p}  \ge \lambda\} ) \le \frac{1}{\lambda} \int_{X}|f_k(x) - f(x) |^{p} ~ d\mu .$$

By our assumption, we obtain:
$$\forall \lambda > 0, ~ ~ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(\{x \in X: |f_n(x) - f(x)|^{p}  \ge \lambda \} )  =  \frac{1}{\lambda}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{X}|f_n(x) - f(x) |^{p} ~ d\mu = 0. ~ ~ (1)$$

We have that,
$$\{x \in X: |f_n(x) - f(x)|^{p}  \ge \lambda \} =\{x \in X: |f_n(x) - f(x)|  \ge (\lambda)^{\frac{1}{p}} \}.  ~ ~ ~ (2)$$

Let $r > 0$. Thus,
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E_{k,r} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\{x \in X: |f_k(x) - f(x) | \ge (r^{p})^{1/p}  \}  = 0,$$

by (1) and (2). Therefore, $\{f_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ converges to $f$ in measure.

Is my proof correct? Any tips on expressing my self better? I have been told that I'm not very good at proving things in analysis, or I have the right ideas but poor execution.

Comment: Your proof looks fine.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you.